# Imitate SharePoint 2010 Ribbons functionality from action button

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to allow some ribbon functionality like "Email a link", "Alert me" , "Export to Excel", "Connect to Outlook" using action buttons ? I'm not able to find Ribbon JS code anywhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the ribbon JS file I do believe that it is at *yourSharePointSite*/_layouts/sp.ribbon.js